# Singularity of piecewise linear (PL-) manifold with non-positive curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $X^3$ be a simply connected piecewise linear(PL-) manifold with non-positive curvature. I am curious about that can we know about the singular set of $X^3$ explicitly. For example, what is the singular set of the hyperbolic space $H^3$?
Is it depend on triangulation of $H^3$?

In my best knowledge, the definition of singular set([Cao and Escobar's paper](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cag/2003/0011/0003/CAG-2003-0011-0003-a004.pdf), Definition 1.10) is as follows.

Let $\tau$ be a given triangulation of $X^3$ and if $k$-dimensional simplex $\sigma^k \subset X^3$ is said to be singular if $Link(\sigma^k, X^3)$ is not isometric to the unit sphere $S^{n-k-1}(1)$.

Comment: You question requires some work. First of all, what do you mean by a PL manifold of nonpositive curvature? Do you mean that each simplex is equipped with a flat metric? Then what do you mean by the hyperbolic space $H^3$ in this context? Or maybe you mean that the metric has constant curvature on each simplex; then $H^3$ makes sense, but the singular locus is empty.

Comment: I think Cao and Escobar's paper considers PL manifold of nonpositive curvature as simplicial complex whose simplices are equipped with flat metric and the metric on the complex is given as [Bridson's paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/bridson/papers/thesis.pdf). Because, in Theorem 4.1,  they used Gauss Bonnet theorem and they calculated total Gaussian curvature of the interior of $\hat{\Omega}$ is zero.

Comment: Thus my question about hyperbolic space seems not appropriate to understand PL manifold with non-positive curvature.

Answer (score 1):

*A long comment:*

- If you remove singular locus, then the remaining part has to be two-convex, as defined "[Sweeping out sectional curvature](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3736)" by Dima Panov and me. In other words, for any direction $\xi$ at a singular point there will be a singular direction $\zeta$ such that $\measuredangle(\xi,\zeta)\le\tfrac\pi2$.
  This is true in all dimensions.
- As far as I know, in 3D case all known examples admit smoothing by Riemannian 3D-manifolds with non-positive sectional curvature.